# Merge uint16_t and int16_t into int32_t for data transmission in C

Tags: c, types

I am confronted with the problem, to transmit an index (uint16_t) and data (int16_t) in a int32_t type, but I had no success yet.

What I tried is the following:

```
int32_t buf = (int16_t) data;
buf |= ((int32_t idx)<<16);
```

But this works only for positive data because of the 2 complement, which adds a one at the MSB. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `buf` should be uint32_t.  `buf = data & 0xffff;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging integer types is a notorious problem in C due to finicky details about integer promotion, representations of integers, and the limits of the definitions of bit shifting.

First, there is rarely a good reason to merge a `uint16_t` and an `int16_t` into an `int32_t` for transmission. One ought to simply access the bytes of the objects using an `unsigned char *` and transmit the bytes. Often, gathering the bytes into a buffer for transmission is easily done using `memcpy`, which is equivalent to copying the bytes using an `unsigned char *`.

If you must merge a `uint16_t` and an `int16_t` into an `int32_t`, with the former going into the high bytes, then a standard-conforming way to do it is:

```
uint32_t temporary = (uint32_t) idx << 16 | (uint16_t) data;
int32_t buf;
memcpy(&buf, &temporary, sizeof buf);
```

Explanation:

- `(uint32_t) idx` widens `idx` to 32 bits, ensuring that it can be shifted by 16 bits without losing any data.
- `(uint16_t) data` converts `data` from `int16_t`, producing a non-negative value of 16 bits that will, when widened to 32 bits, remain non-negative (and not be subject to sign extension).
- Then these two pieces are assembled into a `uint32_t`. (In general, it is easier to work with bit operations using unsigned integers, as they have better semantics for bit operations in C than signed integers do.)
- Finally, the resulting bits are copied into `buf`, side-stepping problems with signed integer overflow and conversion.

[Note that a good compiler will optimize away the `memcpy`.](https://godbolt.org/z/8EZHgd)

To do this without `memcpy`, it is essentially necessary to adjust the `uint16_t` to a signed value:

```
int32_t temporary = 0x8000 <= idx ? idx - 0x10000 : idx;
int32_t buf = temporary * 0x10000 | (uint16_t) data;
```

Or, if the order of `data` and `idx` in `buf` can be changed, an easier solution is:

```
int32_t buf = data * 65536 | idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
uint32_t buf = data & 0xffff; 
buf |= idx<<16;
```

Comment: This fails in implementations where `unsigned int` is 16 bits, since `idx<<16` is evaluated in `unsigned int` arithmetic, and the shift by 16 would be undefined. It fails in implementations where `int` is 32 bits, since `idx<<16` is evaluated in `int` arithmetic and will overflow if its high bit (bit 15) is set.